# ASP .NET Core + Angular 13: Angular material animations visual glitches

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-material, angular-animations

I've recently created my first .NET Core project with out-of-the-box angular template and I planned to utilize Angular Material component library. However, animation effects (in this case material ripple effect and form field select) are glitchy, as shown on GIF below.

[image]

This is the theming I've applied (just a copy paste of what's on the official documentation)

```
$my-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette, 500);
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);
$my-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: $my-primary,
      accent: $my-accent,
      warn: $my-warn,
    ),
  )
);
@include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "oop",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "start:windows": "ng serve --port 44432 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
    "start:default": "ng serve --port 44432 --ssl --ssl-cert $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem --ssl-key $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run oop:server:dev",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.5",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "run-script-os": "^1.1.6",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.29",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.19",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {}
}
```

At first I thought ASP.NET Core generated template uses `NoopAnimationsModule` somewhere and that produces some sort of conflict, but after some digging this doesn't seem to be the case. I've removed all `NoopAnimationsModule` references from the project and it's still the same.

**NOTE: I've tried to switch to NoopAnimationsModule but apart from progress-bar animation disappearing it was all the same**

Second clue is something fishy ASP.NET Core does to Angular Template it generates.

My last clue is SSR, however I am unexperienced with it so it's just a wild guess.

After hours of debuggig I am still clueless, so any help with that one would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The answer in fact is so obvious now. I forgot to add `@include mat.core();` to my `styles.scss` file.